# SWFUpload: how do I implement an upload handler in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, handler, swfupload

i'm a novice-to-intermediate .NET developer and I don't quite understand how an upload handler for SWFUpload is supposed to work.  Am I supposed to read it from the http stream?

I haven't been able to find any examples or explanation of this in the documentation nor from extensive googling.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample implementation: http://svn.swfupload.org/trunk/asp_net/upload.aspx.cs

More info can be found on [SWFUpload website](http://www.swfupload.org/)

Comment: i swear i looked really hard.  

But here it is!  THANK YOU